# Using -> operator in return statements in C

Tags: c, function, return

I am working on learning C, and one of the problems I've encountered, I can't fully understand.  The question is asking what could go wrong if you return using the -> operator.  So if the code originally does this:

```
myVariable = foo->bar;
return myVariable;
```

and then if it was changed to this:

```
return foo->bar;
```

what would go wrong?  It seems like that should still be fine, so I'm not sure why something would go wrong.

Comment: Please post your actual code (up to 20 lines should be fine). It's hard to say from the snippet you posted.

Comment: Edit your post to include the actual text of this question?

Comment: In either case if the variable `foo`  is NULL, the code will crash.  Best to check if foo is NULL before dereferencing it.  If it is NULL, you would return some special value.

Comment: if myVariable is only used as a temp variable that is only returned then it will probably be optimized out such that both implementations compile down to the same assembly.

Answer (score 0):

You're converting from a single-use variable to returning that thing directly. That's allowed and in this case preferable since it avoids any potential mistakes with declaring the wrong type for `myVariable`.

There's nothing special about `->` in the context of a `return`. You can return any *expression*, and things like `->` can be a part of an expression.

If you're curious you can read the [C specification](https://www2.cs.arizona.edu/classes/cs453/fall14/DOCS/cminusminusspec.html) where this is spelled out:

```
return [ expr ] ';'
```

So that means that if `foo->bar` is a valid expression, as in that's a compilable bit of code, then `return foo->bar;` is valid as well. Your code implies `foo` is some kind of pointer to something that has `bar` as a property. If this is not the case then neither version will work. It also depends on the return type of the function in question matching the type of that property.